# Can't Save Highscore - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, save

With this code I get always current score while I want to save high score I try everything to solve it but find nothing.

I want to save hgscr which is highscore , when I call with loadPlayer() I want to compare with topScore which is current score. After all that I call current score and highscore data to my score page.

Player page

```
  if (isStarted == true)
         {
 
             if (rb2d.velocity.y > 0 && transform.position.y > topScore)
             {
                 topScore = transform.position.y;  // Current Score
             }
 
            
             scoreText.text = "Score: " + Mathf.Round(topScore).ToString();         
             
         }
         
         PlayerData data = SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();
         if (topScore > data.hgscrp) // current score  >  where I get highscore data from save page
         {
             hgscr = topScore;  // save highs score for display on score page and compare current score after game restart 
             scsc = Mathf.Round(topScore).ToString();      // save current score for display on score page     
             SaveSystem.SavePlayer(this);
             
         }
         else
         {
             scsc = Mathf.Round(topScore).ToString();
             SaveSystem.SavePlayer(this);
            
         }
 
 
     }
```

Save Page

```
 public string cscore;
     public float hgscrp;
     public PlayerData (Controller player)
 
     {
 
         cscore = player.scsc;
         hgscrp = player.hgscr;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using save/load, try this:

unity has a `PlayerPrefs` class which allows you to save variables which stay the same through restarting the game or switching scenes so if you used :

`PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("VARIABLE NAME",  number);`

If you want to save a highs core this is perfect and to access the saved variable use:

`PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("VARIABLE NAME");`

I hope this works, it did for me :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I try it but it's not show anything on mobile device. Save Load system is work for me . But the problem is while I save current score , highscore is not working...